# How can I get through web service that uses windows authentication from android device via an ssl connection?

Tags: android, web-services, ssl, windows-authentication

I have a webservice hosted at a some location. Now i have an android app that has to connect to that service. I'm currently using ksoap2 to connecto to th web service, which works fine. I've also managed to connect via SSL via some classes i found.

The problem the web service is using windows authentication, and despite my efforts i cannot get authenticated, here is my code:

```
public class Login_Soap 
{
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.service.com/AgentLogin";
    public final String OPERATION_NAME = "AgentLogin"; 
    public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://www.service.com/";
    public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "https://service/Intergration.asmx";

DefaultHttpClient httpclient;

public Login_Soap() 
{ 
    //Constructor
}//end Login_Soap()
public String Call(String Username, String Password)
{
    Log.d("LoginSoap", "Entered");
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    request.addProperty("Username", Username);//object to pass to web service
    request.addProperty("Password", Password);//object to pass to web service

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes= true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    allowAllSSL();//for going through SSL

    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory());
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("https://service/Intergration.asmx", 8080),
    new NTCredentials("username", "Password", "workstation", "domain"));
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 5000);




    NtlmTransport httpTransport = new NtlmTransport();
    httpTransport.setCredentials(SOAP_ADDRESS, "username", "Password", "workstation", "domain");


    httpTransport.debug = true;
    Object response=null;       
    try
    {
        Log.d("LoginSoap", "in try");
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.d("About to login","Trying");
        response = envelope.getResponse();          
        Log.d("SendingHttp", httpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.d("receivinghttp", httpTransport.responseDump);
        Log.d("Soap",  response.toString());
    }//end try
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.d("ExceptionDump", httpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.d("ExceptionResponse", response.toString());
    }//end catch        
    return response.toString();
}//end Call
```

How can i use windows authentication on android???

Comment: Have you got the solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @monish-kamble Unfortunately i have not found a solution for this. My project got de-scoped for this requirement.

Comment: My team was able to do it using JNDI on server-side. I don't know the exact logic behind it. This is being handled on server-side, from android I am just passing username, password.